# Como faço para importar imagem para uma interface tkinter selecionando um arquivo?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Estou fazendo um projeto de sistema escolar e no meu menu principal quero adicionar a foto e ao lado o nome da escola. Quero dar a opção para o usuário mudar a foto quando quiser, mas não consigo fazer um código que selecione a foto de um diretório especifico e salve na interface.**

Essa é minha tentativa de codigo:

````
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os

pastaArq=os.path.dirname(__file__)

def selectImg():
    Tk().withdraw()
    imgLogo= PhotoImage(file=pastaArq+"\\%s") % filename
    image_pos=Label(app, image=imagem)
    image_pos.place(x=10, y=10)

app=Tk() 

app.title("Opções")
app.geometry("320x120")
app.configure(background="#fff")

Label(app, background="#027").place(x=10, y=190, width=114, height=34)
Button(app, text="Editar foto", command=selectImg).place(x=12, y=192, width=110, height=30)

app.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

A formatação da string tem que ficar dentro dos parênteses. O TkInter só suporta ficheiros .png ou .gif. É preciso definir o nome do ficheiro e guardar referência da imagem no atributo img.

```
def selectImg():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = "image.png"
    imagem = PhotoImage(file=pastaArq+"\\%s" % filename) 
    image_pos=Label(app, image=imagem)
    image_pos.img = imagem
    image_pos.place(x=10, y=10)
```